# Is Bluemix FERPA compliant? Specifically related to services such as Dialog, NLC, and Cloudant DB

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have a client in the Higher Education Industry that is interested in a Bluemix solution, but they want to make sure it is FERPA compliant, thank you

Comment: More info needed, What exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Bluemix is not listed as FERPA compliant [in their documentation](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/security/index.html#compliance), so I assume not. Emailing support@bluemix.net can provide a more information.

Comment: Sure. If this answered your question, please mark it as such so others can find it easier when they have the same Q!